# Getting the MVUE of $\sigma^4$ for normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, expected-value, umvue

If x$_{1}$, x$_{2}$,...,x$_{n}$ ~ N($\theta$, $\sigma$$^{2}$), based on the fact that  Y$_{1}$ = $\sum$(x$_{i}$) and Y$_{2}$ =$\sum$(x$_{i}$)$^{2}$ are complete and sufficient statistics, it can be shown that (not sure how)

MVUE of $\sigma$$^{2}$ = $\sum$(x$_{i}$- $\bar x$ )$^{2}$ / (n-1)

If I need to find the MVUE of $\sigma$$^{4}$, can I say it's simply  [$\sum$(x$_{i}$- $\bar x$ )$^{2}$ / (n-1)]$^{2}$ ? I think the answer is no because E[A] $.$ E[A] does not neccessarily equal E [A$^{2}$]. Can someone help me confirm please?

Comment: $E[A^2] = (E[A])^2$ only when $A$ has _zero_ variance, and is thus effectively a constant. So, No, you cannot assume that the MVUE of $\sigma^4$ is simply the square of the MVUE of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: In order to get the MVUE of $\sigma$$^{4}$, should I be thinking of using the chi square distribution?

Comment: You are right. It's calculated in this pdf: http://modelingwithdata.org/pdfs/moments.pdf and as you can see, the formula is very complicated!